# try/catch issues with nested functons in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

I'm having a scenario like below:

```
try {
   top();
} catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
}

function top() {
    nestedFunc1();
}

function nestedFunc1() {
    nestedFunc2();
}

function nestedFunc2() {
 // this function throws an exception.
}
```

my catch block doesn't get executed whenever an exception is thrown in my node script. Is this behaviour expected or i'm missing something here.

Comment: It works in a clean environment: https://repl.it/repls/BuzzingShockedLocus. You need to show us more code which is less "abstract" (meaning that we need to see your actual code)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the code above, an exception from `nestedFunc2` will definitely be caught by that `try`/`catch` block.

My suspicion is that what you really have is an exception in an *asynchronous callback*:

```
try {
    someNodeAPIFunction((err, result) => {
        // Exception thrown here
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

If so, then yes, it's perfectly normal that the `try`/`catch` there doesn't catch the exception, because that code has already finished running. The callback is called **later**. The only thing that can catch the exception is the code in `someNodeAPIFunction` that calls the callback.

This is one of the reasons callback APIs are awkward to work with.

In any vaguely-recent version of Node.js, you can use `async`/`await` to simplify things. Node.js provides Promise-enabled versions of some of its API functions now (in particular the `fs.promises` module) and also provides the [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) utility function that you can use to turn a standard Node.js callback-style function into one that returns a promise. So for instance, with the above:

```
const someNodeAPIFunctionPromisified = util.promisify(someNodeAPIFunction);
```

Then, in an `async` function, you could do this:

```
try {
    const result = await someNodeAPIFunctionPromisified();
    // Exception thrown here
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

...and the exception would be caught, because `async` functions let you right the logical flow of your code even when dealing with asynchronous results.

More about `async` functions [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: (I also cover `async` functions in Chapter 9 of my new book, see my profile for links.)