# App was killed with setTimeout callback func on express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have short question.

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  throw new Error('123')
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

When I call this snippet on express project.
It throw error what I expected.

But

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error('123')
  }, 1000)
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

With this code express process killed with
`Command failed with exit code 1.`
this message.

What keywords should I study is?
What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.The default error handler
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

2.callback error handler
[try/catch issues with nested functons in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716534/try-catch-issues-with-nested-functons-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a simple concept I missed.